# Send FCM Notifications to multiple tokens in PHP using latest HTTP

Tags: php, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send a notifications to multiple tokens using PHP, but its not working. I able to send notification to individual token, but got receiving error for multiple devices. Can anyone Please help?

### multiplenotification:-

```
    $deviceTokens = $token_ids; // Add your device tokens to this array

    $fcmNotifications = [];

    foreach ($deviceTokens as $token_indv) {
        $fcmNotifications[] = [
            'message' => [
                'token' => $token_indv,
                'notification' => $notification,
            ],
        ];
    }

    $headers = [
        'Authorization: Bearer ' . $accessToken,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    ];
    
    echo json_encode($fcmNotifications);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$fcmUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,json_encode($fcmNotifications));  //Post Fields
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    echo $server_output;
```

I am trying to send notification to multiple tokens.

Comment: what **`error`** ?

Comment: What `fcmUrl` are you calling? The versioned API (which is the only one that is not deprecated) does not support sending to multiple tokens with a single call. You will need to make a separate call for each tokens (or consider using topics to reach multiple devices with a single call). See https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-messages-to-multiple-devices

Comment: FCM URL: https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/my-app/messages:send